# Program that prints mirror images of it's own self

Tags: popularity-contest, source-layout

Write a program that produces mirror images of itself.  An example, would be the [fantastic camel code](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=45213) that reads it's own code and produces two smaller 2x2 versions.  Given the input:

```
                                           $_='ev
                                       al("seek\040D
           ATA,0,                  0;");foreach(1..3)
       {<DATA>;}my               @camel1hump;my$camel;
  my$Camel  ;while(             <DATA>){$_=sprintf("%-6
9s",$_);my@dromedary           1=split(//);if(defined($
_=<DATA>)){@camel1hum        p=split(//);}while(@dromeda
 ry1){my$camel1hump=0      ;my$CAMEL=3;if(defined($_=shif
        t(@dromedary1    ))&&/\S/){$camel1hump+=1<<$CAMEL;}
       $CAMEL--;if(d   efined($_=shift(@dromedary1))&&/\S/){
      $camel1hump+=1  <<$CAMEL;}$CAMEL--;if(defined($_=shift(
     @camel1hump))&&/\S/){$camel1hump+=1<<$CAMEL;}$CAMEL--;if(
     defined($_=shift(@camel1hump))&&/\S/){$camel1hump+=1<<$CAME
     L;;}$camel.=(split(//,"\040..m`{/J\047\134}L^7FX"))[$camel1h
      ump];}$camel.="\n";}@camel1hump=split(/\n/,$camel);foreach(@
      camel1hump){chomp;$Camel=$_;y/LJF7\173\175`\047/\061\062\063\
      064\065\066\067\070/;y/12345678/JL7F\175\173\047`/;$_=reverse;
       print"$_\040$Camel\n";}foreach(@camel1hump){chomp;$Camel=$_;y
        /LJF7\173\175`\047/12345678/;y/12345678/JL7F\175\173\0 47`/;
         $_=reverse;print"\040$_$Camel\n";}';;s/\s*//g;;eval;   eval
           ("seek\040DATA,0,0;");undef$/;$_=<DATA>;s/\s*//g;(   );;s
             ;^.*_;;;map{eval"print\"$_\"";}/.{4}/g; __DATA__   \124
               \1   50\145\040\165\163\145\040\157\1 46\040\1  41\0
                    40\143\141  \155\145\1 54\040\1   51\155\  141
                    \147\145\0  40\151\156 \040\141    \163\16 3\
                     157\143\   151\141\16  4\151\1     57\156
                     \040\167  \151\164\1   50\040\      120\1
                     45\162\   154\040\15    1\163\      040\14
                     1\040\1   64\162\1      41\144       \145\
                     155\14    1\162\       153\04        0\157
                      \146\     040\11     7\047\         122\1
                      45\15      1\154\1  54\171          \040
                      \046\         012\101\16            3\16
                      3\15           7\143\15             1\14
                      1\16            4\145\163           \054
                     \040            \111\156\14         3\056
                    \040\         125\163\145\14         4\040\
                    167\1        51\164\1  50\0         40\160\
                  145\162                              \155\151
                \163\163                                \151\1
              57\156\056
```

it produces:

```
        JXXXXXXXXL.       JXXLm.       .mJXXL       .JXXXXXXXXL
       {XXXXXXXXXXX.     JXXXmXXXXm mXXXXmXXXL     .XXXXXXXXXXX}
      .XXXXXXXXXXXXXL.  {XXXXXXXXXF 7XXXXXXXXX}  .JXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
     JXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL.`XXXXXX.       .XXXXXX'.JXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL
    JXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXmXXXXXXX.     .XXXXXXXmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL
  .XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}     {XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
 .XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF       7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 XX'7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF         7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF`XX
 XX {XXXFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF'           `7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7XXX} XX
 `X}{XXX'7XXXFXXXXX^XXXXX `'               `' XXXXX^XXXXX7XXXF`XXX}{X'
  `'XXX' {XXX'XXXXX 7XXXF                     7XXXF XXXXX`XXX} `XXX`'
   .XX}  {XXF {XXXX}`XXX}                     {XXX'{XXXX} 7XX}  {XX.
   {XX   `XXL  `7XX} 7XX}                     {XXF {XXF'  JXX'   XX}
   `XX    `XXL mXXF  {XX                       XX}  7XXm JXX'    XX'
    XX      7XXXF    `XX                       XX'    7XXXF      XX
    XX.    JXXXX.     7X.                     .XF     .XXXXL    .XX
   {XXL    7XF7XXX.   {XX                     XX}   .XXXF7XF    JXX}
   `XXX'              `XXXm                 mXXX'              `XXX'
                       ^^^^^               ^^^^^
    .mJXXL       .JXXXXXXXXL                JXXXXXXXXL.       JXXLm.
 mXXXXmXXXL     .XXXXXXXXXXX}              {XXXXXXXXXXX.     JXXXmXXXXm
 7XXXXXXXXX}  .JXXXXXXXXXXXXX.            .XXXXXXXXXXXXXL.  {XXXXXXXXXF
    .XXXXXX'.JXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL          JXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL.`XXXXXX.
   .XXXXXXXmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL        JXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXmXXXXXXX.
   {XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.    .XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.  .XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF
     7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF`XX  XX'7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF
      `7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7XXX} XX  XX {XXXFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXF'
        `' XXXXX^XXXXX7XXXF`XXX}{X'  `X}{XXX'7XXXFXXXXX^XXXXX `'
           7XXXF XXXXX`XXX} `XXX`'    `'XXX' {XXX'XXXXX 7XXXF
           {XXX'{XXXX} 7XX}  {XX.      .XX}  {XXF {XXXX}`XXX}
           {XXF {XXF'  JXX'   XX}      {XX   `XXL  `7XX} 7XX}
            XX}  7XXm JXX'    XX'      `XX    `XXL mXXF  {XX
            XX'    7XXXF      XX        XX      7XXXF    `XX
           .XF     .XXXXL    .XX        XX.    JXXXX.     7X.
           XX}   .XXXF7XF    JXX}      {XXL    7XF7XXX.   {XX
         mXXX'              `XXX'      `XXX'              `XXXm
        ^^^^^                                              ^^^^^
The use of a camel image in association with Perl is a trademark of O'Reilly &
Associates, Inc. Used with permission.
```

(The copyright text is optional.)

A simpler example would take the input:

```
#######
#
#
######
      #
#     #
 #####
```

and produce:

```
 #####      #####
#     #    #     #
      #    #
######      ######
#                #
#                #
#######    #######

#######    #######
#                #
#                #
######      ######
      #    #
#     #    #     #
 #####      #####
```

The entries should demonstrate art.

This is a popularity contest, so the entry with maximum (up)votes wins!

Comment: Is the goal here code which just mirrors text, or does it have to be a proper quine? Should it actually take input or not?

Comment: @nitro2k01 It should mirror text; it isn't really expected to be a proper quine.  No user input is expected.

Comment: Well your camel 3 and 4 should be upside down to be mirror image of camel 1 and 2 !

Comment: @MukulKumar Either form is ok as long as the output is _artistic_.

Comment: I think the title should be changed to "ɟʃǝs uʍo sʇı ɟo sǝƃɐɯı ɹoɹɹıɯ sʇuıɹd ʇɐɥʇ ɯɐɹƃoɹԀ".

Comment: @devnull Nice - I only just noticed the bounty on this! :)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma As I've mentioned in the bounty message, I felt odd that the answer wasn't really noticed by the community.  Honestly, I didn't even expect that a single answer would address both the challenges in the question.  Your artistic answer without making use of an _esoteric_ language is simply amazing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Bash and common utils

*You may have to install `rev`*

I wasn't satisfied with merely reflecting character positions, it really messes up ascii-art input.  So I tried to reflect characters too, modulo the ascii character set.

```
#!/bin/bash
half_width=39
left='/(q[{d>Ss'
right='\\)p]}b<Zz'
up='\\`!^qwWtupSs_'
down='/,ivdmMfnbZz\-'
function callback () {
line=${2: 0: half_width}
p=$((half_width-${#line}))
printf "%s%${p}s%${p}s%s\n" \
"$line" "" "" "$(rev<<<"$line" \
| tr $left$right $right$left)" ; }
if ! [ "$1" ]; then cat < "$0"; elif
[ "$1" == "-" ]; then cat; else cat < "$1"
fi | mapfile -c1 -Ccallback -t | tee >(tac | tr $up$down $down$up)
```

With no arguments, the script prints itself reflected 2x2, as requested:

```
$ ./2x2.sh
#!/bin/bash                                                        hzad\nid\!#
half_width=39                                                    93=htbiw_flah
left='/(q[{d>Ss'                                              'zZ<b}]p)\'=tfel
right='\\)p]}b<Zz'                                          'sS>d{[q(//'=thgir
up='\\`!^qwWtupSs_'                                        '_zZqutWwp^!`//'=qu
down='/,ivdmMfnbZz\-'                                    '-/sSdnfMmbvi,\'=nwob
function callback () {                                  } () kcadllac noitcnuf
line=${2: 0: half_width}                              {htbiw_flah :0 :2}$=enil
p=$((half_width-${#line}))                          (({enil#}$-htbiw_flah))$=q
printf "%s%${p}s%${p}s%s\n" \                    / "n/z%z{q}$%z{q}$%z%" ftnirq
"$line" "" "" "$(rev<<<"$line" \              / "enil$">>>ver)$" "" "" "enil$"
| tr $left$right $right$left)" ; }          { ; "(tfel$thgir$ thgir$tfel$ rt |
if ! [ "$1" ]; then cat < "$0"; elif      file ;"0$" > tac neht ;[ "1$" ] ! fi
[ "$1" == "-" ]; then cat; else cat < "" > tac ezle ;tac neht ;[ "-" == "1$" ]
fi | mapfile -c1 -Ccallback -t | tee >()< eet | t- kcadllacC- 1c- elifqam | if
t! | wabt!le _c1 _Ccallpack _f | fee >()< eef | f_ kcaqllacC_ 1c_ el!tdaw | !t
[ "$1" == "_" ]; fheu caf; elze caf < "" > fac esle ;fac uehf ;[ "_" == "1$" ]
!t i [ "$1" ]; fheu caf < "$0"; el!t      t!le ;"0$" > fac uehf ;[ "1$" ] i t!
| fr $letf$r!ghf $r!ghf$letf)" ; }          { ; "(ftel$fhg!r$ fhg!r$ftel$ rf |
"$l!ue" "" "" "$(re^<<<"$l!ue" /              \ "eu!l$">>>^er)$" "" "" "eu!l$"
br!uft "%z%${b}z%${b}z%z/u" /                    \ "u\s%s{d}$%s{d}$%s%" tfu!rd
b=$((halt-m!qfh_${#l!ue}))                          (({eu!l#}$_hfp!m-tlah))$=d
l!ue=${2: 0: halt-m!qfh}                              {hfp!m-tlah :0 :2}$=eu!l
tnucf!ou callpack () {                                  } () kcaqllac uo!fcunt
qomu='\`!^qwWtupSs/_'                                    '_\zZqutWwp^!`/'=umop
nb='//,ivdmMfnbZz-'                                        '-sSdnfMmbvi,\\'=dn
r!ghf='//)b]}p<Ss'                                          'zZ>q{[d(\\'=fhg!r
letf='\(d[{q>Zz'                                              'sS<p}]b)/'=ftel
halt-m!qfh=39                                                    93=hfp!m-tlah
#i\p!u\pazh                                                        hsaq/u!q/i#
$
```

You may also provide in input filename:

```
$ ./2x2.sh ppcg.fig 
 ____  ____   ____ ____                                ____ ____   ____  ____ 
|  _ \|  _ \ / ___/ ___|                              |___ \___ \ / _  |/ _  |
| |_) | |_) | |  | |  _                                _  | |  | | (_| | (_| |
|  __/|  __/| |__| |_| |                              | |_| |__| |\__  |\__  |
|_|   |_|    \____\____|                              |____/____/    |_|   |_|
                                                                              
                                                                              
|-|   |-|    /----/----|                              |----\----\    |-|   |-|
|  --\|  --\| |--| |-| |                              | |-| |--| |/--  |/--  |
| |-) | |-) | |  | |  -                                -  | |  | | (-| | (-| |
|  - /|  - / \ ---\ ---|                              |--- /--- / \ -  |\ -  |
 ----  ----   ---- ----                                ---- ----   ----  ---- 
$
```

If the input filename is `-`, the script will read input from stdin:

```
$ cowsay moo | ./2x2.sh -
 _____                                                                  _____ 
< moo >                                                                < oom >
 -----                                                                  ----- 
        \   ^__^                                              ^__^   /        
         \  (oo)\_______                              _______/(oo)  /         
            (__)\       )\/\                      /\/(       /(__)            
                ||----w |                            | w----||                
                ||     ||                            ||     ||                
                ||     ||                            ||     ||                
                ||____m |                            | m____||                
            (--)/       )/\/                      \/\(       \(--)            
         /  (oo)/-------                              -------\(oo)  \         
        /   v--v                                              v--v   \        
 _____                                                                  _____ 
< woo >                                                                < oow >
 -----                                                                  ----- 
$
```

Comment: Amazing!  You did both in one!  Wish I could upvote this n times over.  `echo +1 | ./2x2.sh -`

Comment: @devnull I'm not very good at making the code formatting look pretty, but what I really like is that a back-to-front cow says `oom` and an upside-down cow says `woo`

Comment: You've made the perfect use of what they call _useless use of cat_.

Comment: @devnull I was tormented about the use of `cat` here.  I know I could have removed it completely, but that would have meant repeating almost identical `mapfile` commands 3 times.  I am using "pretty" to justify this use of `cat` ;-)

Comment: Oh! I do understand `bash` a bit to figure it out :-)  (What I meant by in my previous comment was: _cat is damn useful in certain situations_)

Comment: @devnull agreed - `cat` has a bad name IMO, and I will shamelessly use it where I think it is appropriate ;-)

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby

This one definitely took me a while. But it was really fun!

```
#                                  
e=                                
"/+                              
+d.f                            
/(.-.                          
e*0*,+                        
(*1*e/*                      
.-.).,*e                    
/+/(.c.1/                  
,**-c.e**+                
b*,*c+d+++*              
*e.+.0/*+b/+            
+d/+*e/a.1/(*          
0/+*e/*.-/..-/        
*/+.-*1*e.d.)/(      
*0*.+a.a.f.1.e*1    
+b/(/-/,/+*0/+*b/  
+*e/*.-/..-/*/+.-*
1";eval e.tr("#{ }
 ",'').split('').  
each_slice(?\x2.    
ord+0x308333+0+      
-3179315).map{        
#............          
|x|x. join .            
tr(  '(-7',              
'0-9A-F').                
to_i(16).                  
chr.ord.                    
chr.ord                      
.chr.#                        
chr}*                          
'' +                            
''+                              
''                                
#
```

Output:

```
#                                   #
e=                                 ''
"/+                               ''+
+d.f                             '' +
/(.-.                           chr}*
e*0*,+                         .chr.#
(*1*e/*                       chr.ord
.-.).,*e                     chr.ord.
/+/(.c.1/                   to_i(16).
,**-c.e**+                 '0-9A-F').
b*,*c+d+++*               tr(  '(-7',
*e.+.0/*+b/+             |x|x. join .
+d/+*e/a.1/(*           #............
0/+*e/*.-/..-/         -3179315).map{
*/+.-*1*e.d.)/(       ord+0x308333+0+
*0*.+a.a.f.1.e*1     each_slice(?\x2.
+b/(/-/,/+*0/+*b/    ",'').split('').
+*e/*.-/..-/*/+.-* 1";eval e.tr("#{ }
1";eval e.tr("#{ } +*e/*.-/..-/*/+.-*
 ",'').split('').   +b/(/-/,/+*0/+*b/
each_slice(?\x2.     *0*.+a.a.f.1.e*1
ord+0x308333+0+       */+.-*1*e.d.)/(
-3179315).map{         0/+*e/*.-/..-/
#............           +d/+*e/a.1/(*
|x|x. join .             *e.+.0/*+b/+
tr(  '(-7',               b*,*c+d+++*
'0-9A-F').                 ,**-c.e**+
to_i(16).                   /+/(.c.1/
chr.ord.                     .-.).,*e
chr.ord                       (*1*e/*
.chr.#                         e*0*,+
chr}*                           /(.-.
'' +                             +d.f
''+                               "/+
''                                 e=
#                                   #
#                                   #
''                                 e=
''+                               "/+
'' +                             +d.f
chr}*                           /(.-.
.chr.#                         e*0*,+
chr.ord                       (*1*e/*
chr.ord.                     .-.).,*e
to_i(16).                   /+/(.c.1/
'0-9A-F').                 ,**-c.e**+
tr(  '(-7',               b*,*c+d+++*
|x|x. join .             *e.+.0/*+b/+
#............           +d/+*e/a.1/(*
-3179315).map{         0/+*e/*.-/..-/
ord+0x308333+0+       */+.-*1*e.d.)/(
each_slice(?\x2.     *0*.+a.a.f.1.e*1
 ",'').split('').   +b/(/-/,/+*0/+*b/
1";eval e.tr("#{ } +*e/*.-/..-/*/+.-*
+*e/*.-/..-/*/+.-* 1";eval e.tr("#{ }
+b/(/-/,/+*0/+*b/    ",'').split('').
*0*.+a.a.f.1.e*1     each_slice(?\x2.
*/+.-*1*e.d.)/(       ord+0x308333+0+
0/+*e/*.-/..-/         -3179315).map{
+d/+*e/a.1/(*           #............
*e.+.0/*+b/+             |x|x. join .
b*,*c+d+++*               tr(  '(-7',
,**-c.e**+                 '0-9A-F').
/+/(.c.1/                   to_i(16).
.-.).,*e                     chr.ord.
(*1*e/*                       chr.ord
e*0*,+                         .chr.#
/(.-.                           chr}*
+d.f                             '' +
"/+                               ''+
e=                                 ''
#                                   #
```

[image: screenshot]

It's based on the same idea as [my previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22647/3808).

Comment: Aha! this is _extremely_ pretty.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby

**UPDATE**: Check out [my new answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22684/3808), based on the same idea as this one!

```
$,                                    |
   e="s=  open(  $0).r  ead.s  pli    |
   t   (  1   0  .      ch     r);    |
   $   ,  =   3  2      .      chr    |
   ;s=s.  zip(s  .      r ev   ers    |
   e      )      .      m   a         |
   p      (      &:joi  n);pu   t     |
                                      |
s(s+s.reverse)";eval e.gsub(/[\s|]/,'')
```

Output:

```
$,                                    | s(s+s.reverse)";eval e.gsub(/[\s|]/,'')
   e="s=  open(  $0).r  ead.s  pli    |                                       |
   t   (  1   0  .      ch     r);    |    p      (      &:joi  n);pu   t     |
   $   ,  =   3  2      .      chr    |    e      )      .      m   a         |
   ;s=s.  zip(s  .      r ev   ers    |    ;s=s.  zip(s  .      r ev   ers    |
   e      )      .      m   a         |    $   ,  =   3  2      .      chr    |
   p      (      &:joi  n);pu   t     |    t   (  1   0  .      ch     r);    |
                                      |    e="s=  open(  $0).r  ead.s  pli    |
s(s+s.reverse)";eval e.gsub(/[\s|]/,'') $,                                    |
s(s+s.reverse)";eval e.gsub(/[\s|]/,'') $,                                    |
                                      |    e="s=  open(  $0).r  ead.s  pli    |
   p      (      &:joi  n);pu   t     |    t   (  1   0  .      ch     r);    |
   e      )      .      m   a         |    $   ,  =   3  2      .      chr    |
   ;s=s.  zip(s  .      r ev   ers    |    ;s=s.  zip(s  .      r ev   ers    |
   $   ,  =   3  2      .      chr    |    e      )      .      m   a         |
   t   (  1   0  .      ch     r);    |    p      (      &:joi  n);pu   t     |
   e="s=  open(  $0).r  ead.s  pli    |                                       |
$,                                    | s(s+s.reverse)";eval e.gsub(/[\s|]/,'')
```

It's "PPCG!" in ASCII art! :D

Here's a detailed explanation. First, I found out how to do the actual mirroring. Here's the mirroring code:

```
s = open($0).read.split "\n"
$, = ' '
s = s.zip(s.reverse).map &:join
puts s + s.reverse
```

Then I had to remove whitespace characters and double quotes (because escaping just gets messy), so I used Ruby's `Fixnum#chr`.

The basic structure of the program is now:

```
e="<code>"
eval e.gsub(/\s/,'')
```

Now I can make it into ASCII art! So, that's what I did. Then, I padded the ASCII art with spaces and `|`s at the end, and I made it to here:

```
e="s=  open(  $0).r  ead.s  pli       |
t   (  1   0  .      ch     r);       |
$   ,  =   3  2      .      chr       |
;s=s.  zip(s  .      r ev   ers       |
e      )      .      m   a            |
p      (      &:joi  n);pu   t        |
s(s+s.reverse)";eval e.gsub(/[\s|]/,'')
```

However, that looked a bit ugly, since there wasn't enough padding around the ASCII art. Therefore, I added a bit of extra padding, and got where I am now! (`$, | x` is equivalent to `x` since `$,` is `nil` by default.)

Comment: This is artistic!

Comment: Didn't notice the _evil_ `eval` earlier :)

Answer (score 5):

### bash ( + `sed`  + `tee` + `tac` ) -> 102

```
sed -re 'h;s/$/\o1/;:a;s/(.)\o1(.*)$/\o1\2\1/;ta;s/^\o1//;G;s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 \1/' ${1:-$0}|tee >(tac)
```

Sample useable

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -re 'h;s/$/\o1/;:a;s/(.)\o1(.*)$/\o1\2\1/;ta;
         s/^\o1//;G;s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 \1/' ${1:-$0} |
    tee >(tac)
```

Sample detailed:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -re '
    h;         # copy current line to hold space
    s/$/\o1/;  # add chr(1) at end of line
   :a;         # branch label for further goto
    s/(.)\o1(.*)$/\o1\2\1/; # move 1 char at end to end
    ta;        # goto :a if previous `s///` do match
    s/^\o1//;  # drop chr(1)
    G;         # Append newline + hold space to current line
    s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 \1/ # Suppress newline and swap line <-> hold space
' ${1:-$0} |   # From file as first arg or script himself, than pipe  to
    tee >(     # tee would double stdout and pass feed to
      tac )    # tac as reverse cat.
```

This could result as:

```
./revmir.sh
#!/bin/bash hsab/nib/!#

sed -re ' ' er- des
    h;         # copy current line to hold space ecaps dloh ot enil tnerruc ypoc #         ;h    
    s/$/\o1/;  # add chr(1) at end of line enil fo dne ta )1(rhc dda #  ;/1o\/$/s    
   :a;         # branch label for further goto otog rehtruf rof lebal hcnarb #         ;a:   
    s/(.)\o1(.*)$/\o1\2\1/; # move 1 char at end to end dne ot dne ta rahc 1 evom # ;/1\2\1o\/$)*.(1o\).(/s    
    ta;        # goto :a if previous `s///` do match hctam od `///s` suoiverp fi a: otog #        ;at    
    s/^\o1//;  # drop chr(1) )1(rhc pord #  ;//1o\^/s    
    G;         # Append newline + hold space to current line enil tnerruc ot ecaps dloh + enilwen dneppA #         ;G    
    s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 \1/ # Suppress newline and swap line <-> hold space ecaps dloh >-< enil paws dna enilwen sserppuS # /1\ 2\/$)*.(n\)*.(^/s    
' ${1:-$0} |   # From file as first arg or script himself, than pipe  to ot  epip naht ,flesmih tpircs ro gra tsrif sa elif morF #   | }0$-:1{$ '
    tee >(     # tee would double stdout and pass feed to ot deef ssap dna tuodts elbuod dluow eet #     (> eet    
      tac )    # tac as reverse cat. .tac esrever sa cat #    ) cat      


      tac )    # tac as reverse cat. .tac esrever sa cat #    ) cat      
    tee >(     # tee would double stdout and pass feed to ot deef ssap dna tuodts elbuod dluow eet #     (> eet    
' ${1:-$0} |   # From file as first arg or script himself, than pipe  to ot  epip naht ,flesmih tpircs ro gra tsrif sa elif morF #   | }0$-:1{$ '
    s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 \1/ # Suppress newline and swap line <-> hold space ecaps dloh >-< enil paws dna enilwen sserppuS # /1\ 2\/$)*.(n\)*.(^/s    
    G;         # Append newline + hold space to current line enil tnerruc ot ecaps dloh + enilwen dneppA #         ;G    
    s/^\o1//;  # drop chr(1) )1(rhc pord #  ;//1o\^/s    
    ta;        # goto :a if previous `s///` do match hctam od `///s` suoiverp fi a: otog #        ;at    
    s/(.)\o1(.*)$/\o1\2\1/; # move 1 char at end to end dne ot dne ta rahc 1 evom # ;/1\2\1o\/$)*.(1o\).(/s    
   :a;         # branch label for further goto otog rehtruf rof lebal hcnarb #         ;a:   
    s/$/\o1/;  # add chr(1) at end of line enil fo dne ta )1(rhc dda #  ;/1o\/$/s    
    h;         # copy current line to hold space ecaps dloh ot enil tnerruc ypoc #         ;h    
sed -re ' ' er- des

#!/bin/bash hsab/nib/!#
```

or formated to fixed line width:

```
printf -v spc '%74s';sed "s/\$/$spc/;s/^\(.\{74\}\) *$/\1/" <revmir.sh | ./revmir.sh -
```

give:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                               hsab/nib/!#

sed -re '                                                                                                                                   ' er- des
    h;         # copy current line to hold space                                                     ecaps dloh ot enil tnerruc ypoc #         ;h    
    s/$/\o1/;  # add chr(1) at end of line                                                                 enil fo dne ta )1(rhc dda #  ;/1o\/$/s    
   :a;         # branch label for further goto                                                         otog rehtruf rof lebal hcnarb #         ;a:   
    s/(.)\o1(.*)$/\o1\2\1/; # move 1 char at end to end                                       dne ot dne ta rahc 1 evom # ;/1\2\1o\/$)*.(1o\).(/s    
    ta;        # goto :a if previous `s///` do match                                             hctam od `///s` suoiverp fi a: otog #        ;at    
    s/^\o1//;  # drop chr(1)                                                                                             )1(rhc pord #  ;//1o\^/s    
    G;         # Append newline + hold space to current line                             enil tnerruc ot ecaps dloh + enilwen dneppA #         ;G    
    s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 \1/ # Suppress newline and swap line <-> hold space   ecaps dloh >-< enil paws dna enilwen sserppuS # /1\ 2\/$)*.(n\)*.(^/s    
' ${1:-$0} |   # From file as first arg or script himself, than pipe  to     ot  epip naht ,flesmih tpircs ro gra tsrif sa elif morF #   | }0$-:1{$ '
    tee >(     # tee would double stdout and pass feed to                                   ot deef ssap dna tuodts elbuod dluow eet #     (> eet    
      tac )    # tac as reverse cat.                                                                             .tac esrever sa cat #    ) cat      


      tac )    # tac as reverse cat.                                                                             .tac esrever sa cat #    ) cat      
    tee >(     # tee would double stdout and pass feed to                                   ot deef ssap dna tuodts elbuod dluow eet #     (> eet    
' ${1:-$0} |   # From file as first arg or script himself, than pipe  to     ot  epip naht ,flesmih tpircs ro gra tsrif sa elif morF #   | }0$-:1{$ '
    s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2 \1/ # Suppress newline and swap line <-> hold space   ecaps dloh >-< enil paws dna enilwen sserppuS # /1\ 2\/$)*.(n\)*.(^/s    
    G;         # Append newline + hold space to current line                             enil tnerruc ot ecaps dloh + enilwen dneppA #         ;G    
    s/^\o1//;  # drop chr(1)                                                                                             )1(rhc pord #  ;//1o\^/s    
    ta;        # goto :a if previous `s///` do match                                             hctam od `///s` suoiverp fi a: otog #        ;at    
    s/(.)\o1(.*)$/\o1\2\1/; # move 1 char at end to end                                       dne ot dne ta rahc 1 evom # ;/1\2\1o\/$)*.(1o\).(/s    
   :a;         # branch label for further goto                                                         otog rehtruf rof lebal hcnarb #         ;a:   
    s/$/\o1/;  # add chr(1) at end of line                                                                 enil fo dne ta )1(rhc dda #  ;/1o\/$/s    
    h;         # copy current line to hold space                                                     ecaps dloh ot enil tnerruc ypoc #         ;h    
sed -re '                                                                                                                                   ' er- des

#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                               hsab/nib/!#
```

and using `figlet`:

```
figlet -f banner 5 | ./revmir.sh -
#######   #######
#               #
#               #
######     ######
      #   #      
#     #   #     #
 #####     ##### 


 #####     ##### 
#     #   #     #
      #   #      
######     ######
#               #
#               #
#######   #######
```

And for fun:

```
figlet -f banner Code Golf. | ./asciiReduce |  ./revmir.sh -
▞▀▀▖▗▄▖▗▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▞▀▀▖▗▄▖▗   ▄▄▄       ▄▄▄   ▗▖▄▗▖▀▀▞  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▗▖▄▗▖▀▀▞
▌   ▌ ▐▐  ▌▙▄▖  ▌▗▄▖▌ ▐▐   ▙▄▖       ▖▄▙   ▐▐ ▌▖▄▗▌  ▖▄▙▌  ▐▐ ▌   ▌
▌  ▖▌ ▐▐  ▌▌    ▌  ▌▌ ▐▐   ▌  ▐█   █▐  ▌   ▐▐ ▌▌  ▌    ▌▌  ▐▐ ▌▖  ▌
▝▀▀ ▝▀▘▝▀▀ ▀▀▀  ▝▀▀ ▝▀▘▝▀▀▘▘  ▝▀   ▀▝  ▘▘▀▀▝▘▀▝ ▀▀▝  ▀▀▀ ▀▀▝▘▀▝ ▀▀▝

▝▀▀ ▝▀▘▝▀▀ ▀▀▀  ▝▀▀ ▝▀▘▝▀▀▘▘  ▝▀   ▀▝  ▘▘▀▀▝▘▀▝ ▀▀▝  ▀▀▀ ▀▀▝▘▀▝ ▀▀▝
▌  ▖▌ ▐▐  ▌▌    ▌  ▌▌ ▐▐   ▌  ▐█   █▐  ▌   ▐▐ ▌▌  ▌    ▌▌  ▐▐ ▌▖  ▌
▌   ▌ ▐▐  ▌▙▄▖  ▌▗▄▖▌ ▐▐   ▙▄▖       ▖▄▙   ▐▐ ▌▖▄▗▌  ▖▄▙▌  ▐▐ ▌   ▌
▞▀▀▖▗▄▖▗▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▞▀▀▖▗▄▖▗   ▄▄▄       ▄▄▄   ▗▖▄▗▖▀▀▞  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▗▖▄▗▖▀▀▞
```

He, he... This could not work because of half-chars could not be simply reversed.

For this, we have to run command in reversed order:

```
figlet -f banner Code Golf. |  ./revmir.sh - | asciiReduce 
▞▀▀▖▗▄▖▗▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▞▀▀▖▗▄▖▗   ▄▄▄     ▗▄▄▖  ▗ ▄▄ ▞▀▀▖ ▗▄▄▖▗▄▄ ▄▄ ▞▀▀▖
▌   ▌ ▐▐  ▌▙▄▖  ▌▗▄▖▌ ▐▐   ▙▄▖      ▄▄▌  ▐▐  ▌▄▄ ▌  ▄▄▌▌ ▐▐  ▌   ▌
▌  ▖▌ ▐▐  ▌▌    ▌  ▌▌ ▐▐   ▌  ▐█ ▐█   ▌  ▐▐  ▌▌  ▌    ▌▌ ▐▐  ▌▖  ▌
▝▀▀ ▝▀▘▝▀▀ ▀▀▀  ▝▀▀ ▝▀▘▝▀▀▘▘  ▝▀ ▝▀   ▘▀▀▀ ▀▀ ▝▀▀  ▝▀▀▘▝▀▀ ▀▀ ▝▀▀ 
▗▄▄ ▗▄▖▗▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▗▄▄ ▗▄▖▗▄▄▖▖  ▗▄ ▗▄   ▖▄▄▄ ▄▄ ▗▄▄  ▗▄▄▖▗▄▄ ▄▄ ▗▄▄ 
▌  ▘▌ ▐▐  ▌▌    ▌  ▌▌ ▐▐   ▌  ▐█ ▐█   ▌  ▐▐  ▌▌  ▌    ▌▌ ▐▐  ▌▘  ▌
▌   ▌ ▐▐  ▌▛▀▘  ▌▝▀▘▌ ▐▐   ▛▀▘      ▀▀▌  ▐▐  ▌▀▀ ▌  ▀▀▌▌ ▐▐  ▌   ▌
▚▄▄▘▝▀▘▝▀▀ ▀▀▀  ▚▄▄▘▝▀▘▝   ▀▀▀     ▝▀▀▘  ▝ ▀▀ ▚▄▄▘ ▝▀▀▘▝▀▀ ▀▀ ▚▄▄▘
```

[image: code golf mirrored and reduced]

Comment: Is this '▝' intentional  or means unknown character ?

Comment: Still can't understand that ;(

Comment: +1.  My guess for the downvote is your first example output doesn't do the padding, and the downvoter didn't bother reading further.  I see you go on to implement padding, so personally I would edit the answer just to include that.

Answer (score 2):

## C++

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char mirror[]={ 218,196,196,196,196,196,191,
                    218,196,196,196,196,196,191,'\n',
                    179,201,205,203,205,187,179,
                    179,201,205,203,205,187,179,'\n',
                    179,186,254,186,254,186,179,
                    179,186,254,186,254,186,179,'\n',
                    179,204,205,206,205,185,179,
                    179,204,205,206,205,185,179,'\n',
                    179,186,254,186,254,186,179,
                    179,186,254,186,254,186,179,'\n',
                    179,200,205,202,205,188,179,
                    179,200,205,202,205,188,179,'\n',
                    192,196,196,196,196,196,217,
                    192,196,196,196,196,196,217,'\n',
                    '\0'};
    std::cout<<mirror<<mirror;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

#### output

This output looks like "Windows 4X4".

> [image]

Comment: No one likes my post ... T_T why ?

Comment: Maybe because it hardcodes (!) the output in CP-437 (!)? Also it's only an hour old.

Comment: @mniip doorknob's post is only 12 minutes old!

Comment: I don't know why, but people vote for the high-rep users quicker.  I will vote for you as soon as I get my voting power back.

Comment: How is this a mirrored image of the source code? It looks completely different

Comment: @TomDoodler do we have to make mirror images of the code?